# "It has been revised 6 times" vs "It was revised 6 times"

Tags: present-perfect

Below is a quote from an article [Scrum software development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrum_(software_development)):

> Since 2009, a public document called The Scrum Guide[18] has been published and updated by Schwaber and Sutherland. **It has been revised 6 times**, with the current version being November 2020.

Why is the present perfect used in "It has been revised 6 times"? Why not the simple past tense? Could the simple past tense be used here? What would be the difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The choice of tense carries the implication that the document may well be revised again. The paragraph implies that it is being regularly updated.

*It was revised six times* would be used if a book had been repeatedly edited and then finally published in its definitive form.

Comment: Is it still possible for a native English speaker to use the simple past here: "It was revised 6 times, with the current version being November 2020". In other words, does this sentence strike you as being non natural, non common?

Comment: It's not a question of how 'common' the expression is - it conveys the idea that the document is not expected to be revised again, which doesn't fit with the second phrase about the 'current' version.

Answer (score 2):

1

> It **has been** revised 6 times, with the current version being November 2020.

2

> It **was** revised 6 times[.]

The present perfect tense version expresses a likelihood that the document may be further revised.  The subordinate clause, with 'current', further reinforces this point.

The simple past tense version gives a sense that there should not be any further revision.  The subordinate clause in example 1 will probably not be used.